# The correctness of chosen items

Tags: tenses

I faced with interesting (in my opinion) questions. 
I have an exersice I must choose the correct tenses for:

1. He was going along the beach one day. He (not / look) where he was going.
2. "What (be) this?" he said, picking up the object he (trip) over.
3. "I (never / see) anything like it before".It was, in fact, a very old lamp, and as he (rub) it, suddenly a genie (fly) out of it.

I put next items:

1. wasn't looking (at that moment)
2. is, tripped
3. I've never seen (experience), rubbed (succession of actions), flew (succession of actions)

But there were other answers in the keys:

1. hadn't been looking (action of some duration before another one continuing up to that time???) / was looking
2. is, had tripped over (action happend before another one???)
3. I've never seen, was rubbing (as it was a process, but my answer is correct too???), flew

Help me, please

Comment: Whoever set that exercise doesn't really know how native speakers use verb tenses.

Comment: @PeterShor, exuse my  ignorance if something is wrong. Actually I'm not a native speaker. So am I right? It's realy important to spot  the correct answer in order not to make mistakes in future?

Comment: I think your number 1 and 3 answers are perfectly acceptable. For  2, while many native speakers would say “tripped” in everyday speech, I think “had tripped” is more likely to be accepted by an English teacher.

Comment: @Jim, I am not an impertenant person but taking an opportunity I would like to ask you about a consultation about one more question I am interested in: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/117608/what-should-i-use-past-perfect-or-past-simple

Comment: 2 is *had tripped* because of the sequence. He tripped and then said something. The trip is further back in the time than "said", so it needs the pluperfect/past perfect. I reckon your answers to 1 and 3 are not just acceptable but actually at least as good as the suggested answers, if not better.